# Alluvial or Sankey diagram generated with Python, using d3py?

Tags: javascript, python, d3.js, sankey-diagram, d3py

I'd like to create a Sankey or alluvial diagram using [d3py](https://github.com/mikedewar/d3py), d3.js, and its [sankey.js](https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins/tree/master/sankey) plugin, but I don't know how to reach this JavaScript library and the plugin from d3py.

Can someone get me started here?